# Unable to install extension 'ms-python.python' as it is not compatible with VS Code '1.39.2'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Due to the company policy, I cannot upgrade the vs code version. My vs code version is 1.39.2.

I want to the install python extension and got the error on title. I downloaded the vsix and tried to install it manually and got the same error.

Why not provide the old version of the extension to download?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer on this extension. In the marketplace tab in VSCode you can right click the python extension and select "Install another version" when you do that it will pop up a list of all the old versions of the extension. This should allow you to go back and find the version that works for your VSCode.

Comment: How to do that on mac? Right click on mac does not popup anything?

Comment: I'm on macOS as well. When I right click I get this:
https://imgur.com/a/zqRRARb . that option then opens a list of versions to install from the top command palette of vscode.