# Unable to install extension 'ms-python.python' on latest MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have installed `python3` via brew (although `python` still uses the macOS version):

```
➜  ~ which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
➜  ~ which python
/usr/bin/python
➜  ~
```

I believe changing `python` to brew may create system instabilities.  I have explicitly set python3 to use brew (i.e. `"python.pythonPath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/python3"`).

Upon installation of the `ms-python.python` extension, I get these two errors:

- workbench.desktop.main.js:734: workbench.desktop.main.js:1904: Activating extension 'ms-python.python' failed: Expected a string, got undefined.
- workbench.desktop.main.js:1904: Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information.

Here is the information about VSCode:

```
Version: 1.55.2 (Universal)
Commit: 3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d
Date: 2021-04-13T09:36:32.643Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 11.3.0
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
Node.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 20.3.0
```

(MacOS version 11.2.3: BigSur)

I have tried a older versions of the extension and they don't work.  Any thoughts?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2654002/ian-huff
https://stackoverflow.com/users/15093821/luciana-abud

Potentially related to
[Unable to install extension 'ms-python.python' as it is not compatible with VS Code '1.39.2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203296/unable-to-install-extension-ms-python-python-as-it-is-not-compatible-with-vs-c#)
[Error loading Python for VS Code IntelliCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301266/error-loading-python-for-vs-code-intellicode)

Comment: Where was the key `'python.pythonPath'` set?

Comment: @Tianhui Li -You could try to find the VS Code extension installation folder (_username\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.xxx_), and remove or delete the "Python" extension folder, then reopen VS Code and restart Install the "Python" extension.